# Elixir: How to get the current date for an Ecto Query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

It is a bit of a joke that I have to ask this but it is really not clear what the best way is. So this might turn into a little rant. But I have the fealing that Elixir lacks seriously here.

I find it quite complicated to get the current date to query in Ecto agains the current date. For example for something like `get me every record where date column x contains a date before t`.

As of now I use Erlangs `:calendar.universal_time()`, pass that to `Ecto.DateTime.from_erl` and that again to `Ecto.Date.cast`.

```
date = :calendar.universal_time() |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl |> Ecto.Date.cast
```

Note that we also have to pattern match the actual date, since we get back a tuple

```
{:ok, #Ecto.Date<2016-10-25>}
```

So it is

```
{:ok, date} = :calendar.universal_time() |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl |> Ecto.Date.cast
```

Of course I could use `Ecto.Date.cast!` but that again is something you have to find out and could have some downsides I'm not aware of.

Then I can build the query. But I have to call at least 3 functions everytime...

```
query = from m in Model, select: {m.name, m.email}, where: (m.canceled_to > ^date), order_by: [desc: m.inserted_at]
result = Repo.all(query)
```

So is there a better way that I'm missing?

Comment: Doesn't `Ecto.Date.utc/0` work for you? - https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Date.html#utc/0

Comment: Hah. That was the one I was looking for... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current date in Ecto - [Ecto.Date.utc/0](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.6/Ecto.Date.html#utc/0)

Answer (score 2):

The Ecto.Date module is now depreciated; however, you can use the regular Elixir Date like: `^Date.utc_today()`.

Comment: I think that's the best answer up to date.